# How can I use Manjaro in google compute engine with GUI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to use Manjaro in GCP compute engine with GUI but there isn't any image available in compute engine

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Manjaro in your own machine first using something like VirtualBox. Then you can upload the local boot disk to GCS and use that.

See details here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks

Seems Manjaro is based on Arch but GCP only supports CentOS/Debian/Red Hat/Ubuntu
(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#supported_operating_systems)

Don't if it will work.

For GUI, you need to install X and VNC server then use vnc client to connect.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what [Cloud Ace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11474744/cloud-ace) already mentions, there's another resource I believe you might find of interest.

There is actually an [ArchLinux dedicated repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-archlinux-image-builder) in the official GCP GitHub page, which contains some instructions as per how to install ArchLinux into a GCE instance by either using a preconfigured image in the available public images in GCP or building yourself your own custom image. I believe the process of building an image could be attempted with Manjaro, given the fact that it is originally intended for ArchLinux. It has potential to work.

In the end, if the custom image building does not work out with Manjaro, you can always use the Arch Linux public image mentioned in the GitHub I shared (which is the minimal base Arch Linux image), and install the desktop environment you like.

Hope this helps.